# what is the difference between two ways of array declaration and initialization in java

Tags: java, arrays

We can declare and initialize a single dimensional array in one of the two ways

one we can declare using new keyword and in other we dont use new keyword. So how does memory allocation is done when we are not using the new keyword. 
Also, when should we go for new declaration when working with array in java

```
int []a = new int[5];
a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
a[2]=3;
a[3]=4;
a[4]=5;

int []b = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Comment: The way you write it is literally the only difference. Those two initializations are semantically the same. A remark: in Java, the array bracket should be directly after the type, not in front of the variable name, since they influence the type: `int []b` -> `int[] b`

Comment: @Turing85: thank you for the explanation, so this implies that using the second way of declaration and initialization would also work the same way like new keyword.Behind the scene it would allocate memory like it is done with new keyword. It only the semantic difference.

Comment: "*It only the semantic difference.*" - If by "semantic" you mean "syntactic", then yes =)

Comment: @Turing85: yes, thanks again for the clarification !

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments: There is no difference in practice. So the difference is mainly *syntactical*.

---

This may be a few more details than you have been asking for, but: It is not *entirely* syntactical. Interestingly, the bytecode is slightly different. Consider this class:

```
class ArrayInit
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        initA();
        initB();
    }


    public static void initA()
    {
        int []a = new int[5];
        a[0]=1;
        a[1]=2;
        a[2]=3;
        a[3]=4;
        a[4]=5;
    }

    public static void initB()
    {
        int[] b = {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}
```

Compiling it and disassembling the resulting `class` file with

```
javap -c ArrayInit
```

prints the resulting byte code of both methods. A side-by-side comparison of the byte codes of both methods is shown here:

```
public static void initA();     public static void initB(); 
  Code:                              Code:
     0: iconst_5                        0: iconst_5
     1: newarray       int              1: newarray       int
     3: astore_0                         
     4: aload_0                         3: dup
     5: iconst_0                        4: iconst_0
     6: iconst_1                        5: iconst_1
     7: iastore                         6: iastore
     8: aload_0                         7: dup
     9: iconst_1                        8: iconst_1
    10: iconst_2                        9: iconst_2
    11: iastore                        10: iastore
    12: aload_0                        11: dup
    13: iconst_2                       12: iconst_2
    14: iconst_3                       13: iconst_3
    15: iastore                        14: iastore
    16: aload_0                        15: dup
    17: iconst_3                       16: iconst_3
    18: iconst_4                       17: iconst_4
    19: iastore                        18: iastore
    20: aload_0                        19: dup
    21: iconst_4                       20: iconst_4
    22: iconst_5                       21: iconst_5
    23: iastore                        22: iastore
                                       23: astore_0
    24: return                         24: return
```

One can see that basically, in the first variant, which uses `new` and assigns the array elements individually, the reference to the array is pulled on the stack using [`aload_0` instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.aload_n). In the direct initialization, the reference is already on the stack, and just duplicated with [`dup` instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dup).

However, the difference is negligible, and in the end, does not matter at all: When extending the program slightly so that the methods are called a few thousand times, and examining the resulting machine code with `java -server -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly` shows that the machine code of both methods will in fact be **identical** eventually.